# Comparing two discrete paired datasets

Tags: hypothesis-testing, goodness-of-fit, discrete-data, paired-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank

**The problem:** I am studying the estimated number of cases of malaria in regions of the world and found that both the WHO and IHME have their own estimates. I want to find if the difference between the two is statistically significant, but I have no idea which test to use.

The data looks like this:

```
|  Region   |  WHO Est. | IHME Est. |
_____________________________________
| Africa    | 200500000 | 180539272 |
| Americas  | 976000    | 1206022   |
| S.E. Asia | 11290000  | 15842661  |
| West Pac. | 1857000   | 1453467   |
| Europe    | 0         | 0         |
| Mid. East | 4410000   | 9606797   |`
```

**What I've tried:** At first, I thought I could do a chi-square goodness-of-fit test, but I realized there was no "expected," since both sets of estimates were "observed." Then I did some research and found the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, but discarded that because the data is not continuous. I also kept seeing t-tests and many other tests that I didn't work with the data because I wasn't working with a sample mean. Then I came across the Wilcoxon test, and I thought it might be the answer, but I wasn't sure. Please help me figure out which test to use, I'm desperate!

If there is some way to incorporate the confidence intervals of each estimate that would be a great bonus. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Take the ratio of each regions estimate for the number of cases.

This is now a hypothesis testing is to whether the average of the ratios is statistical different from one. However, it is more likely that ratio data is NOT normally distributed. One usually proceeds in this situation by taking the log of the ratios, and computing a confidence interval and determining if it includes zero (which corresponds to a test of the ratios are different from one). See [details here](https://libguides.library.kent.edu/SPSS/OneSampletTest) on 'One Sample Test'.

One could average the transformed (via log) of the column's data points and consider this a ratio test for two means using a log transform. In this case, see expanded [discussion here](https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Tests_for_the_Ratio_of_Two_Means.pdf) detailing 'Tests for the Ratio of Two Means'.

Comment: Would it be possible to do a chi-square goodness-of-fit test on the ratios with the expected being 1?